# Difference between allocating memory in struct and main?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I have two simple structures like this:

```
struct Point{
    double x, y;
};
```

What is the difference between defining like this

```
struct Circle{
    Point *P;
    float radius;
};
```

and this

```
struct Circle{
    Point *P = new Point;
    float radius;
};
```

Is there any advantages if I use the first sample and do something like this in the `main` function

```
Circle *C = new Circle;
C -> P = new Point;
```

Comment: This is not `C`. You cannot do this: `struct Circle{
    Point *P = new Point;;
    float radius;
};` in C.

Comment: This is C++11 to be precise

Comment: It would be more advantageous to use `std::unique_ptr` or another shared pointer. It would probably be even better to not use pointers and have all the structs contained by-value.

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
struct Circle{
    Point *P = new Point;
    float radius;
};
```

Uses C++11 in-class initialization.  What this means is that by default, if no other constructor does otherwise (there is none in your example), `P` will be set to `new Point` for any constructed `Circle`.  This is equivalent but less lines of code to your example where you explicitly set `P` after creating a `Circle`.

Of course, with the example code you've provided, you'd be better off just using a value instead of a pointer:

```
struct Circle{
    Point P;
    float radius;
};
```

Then there will always be a `Point` inside a `Circle`, and we won't have to have a long awkward conversation about resource management, memory leaks, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any performance or behavioural difference between your two examples, but generally, you should put resource allocation (and deallocation) in the class that owns the data. That way, it is logical who is responsible for allocation and deallocation.

I'm assuming this is a simplified example, and won't suggest removing the pointers altogether.

Answer (score 2):

This is a C++11 feature: *in-class initialization* for non-static data members and directly initializes the pointer by allocating memory ([if no other constructor does the same thing in the member initialization list of a constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization))

```
struct Circle{
    Point *P = new Point;
    float radius;
};
```

it is equivalent (i.e. no performance differences) to

```
Circle *C = new Circle;
C -> P = new Point;
```

but you should **not** use both of them otherwise you'll leak memory. A smart pointer is suggested though.

For an object like `Point` I'm also recommending to keeping it as a subobject, not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There is not driect advantage and little difference, between the two solutions.

However, SERIOUSLY consider NOT using dynamic allocation and pointers to store such tiny data structures[1]. This is because dynamic allocation not only takes extra time (call `new`), but also more memory (in most OS's there is an overhead of 16 bytes or more, and the size is rounded up to at least 16 byte boundaries in x86 architectures, to allow SSE access of dynamically allocated memory). So your 16 bytes of two `double` is now taking up 8 bytes for the pointer, and 32 bytes of allocated space (overhead + rounding), making a total of 40 bytes - 24 bytes more than if it was placed directly in the circle object.

And every time (well, the first in any function) you access the `P` member, there needs to be a pointer dereference to find the location of `x` and `y` inside the `Point`.

And you need to make sure you `delete` the `Point` object in some way.

There are of course cases where pointers to small objects are necessary, such as when they have virtual member functions.

[1] In particular since I'd say your `Circle` object is useless without a `Point` to define where your circle is location. There is an argument for using pointers when the object is optional, since you can then use `NULL` to indicate that it's not present.